# Correlated Subqueries with MAX() and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have the issue using MAX() and GROUP BY. 
I have next tables:

personal_prizes

```
 ___________ ___________ _________ __________
|    id     |    userId |   specId| group    |  
|___________|___________|_________|__________|
|    1      |    1      |   1     |     1    |  
|___________|___________|_________|__________|
|    2      |    1      |   2     |     1    |  
|___________|___________|_________|__________|
|    3      |    2      |   3     |     1    |  
|___________|___________|_________|__________|
|     4     |    2      |   4     |     2    |  
|___________|___________|_________|__________|
|     5     |    1      |   5     |     2    |  
|___________|___________|_________|__________|
|     6     |    1      |   6     |     2    |  
|___________|___________|_________|__________|
|    7      |    2      |   7     |     3    |  
|___________|___________|_________|__________|


prizes
 ___________ ___________ _________ 
|    id     |    title  |   group |     
|___________|___________|_________|
|    1      |    First  |   1     | 
|___________|___________|_________|
|    2      |    Second |   1     | 
|___________|___________|_________|
|    3      |    Newby  |   1     | 
|___________|___________|_________|
|     4     |    General|   2     | 
|___________|___________|_________|
|     5     |    Leter  |   2     | 
|___________|___________|_________|
|     6     |    Ter    |   2     | 
|___________|___________|_________|
|     7     |    Mentor |   3     | 
|___________|___________|_________|
```

So, I need to select highest title for user.
E.g. user with id = 1 must have prizes 'Second', 'Ter'. 
I don't know how to implement it in one query(((
So, first of all, I try to select highest specID for user.
I try next:

```
SELECT pp.specID 
FROM personal_prizes pp
WHERE pp.specID IN (SELECT MAX(pp1.id) 
                    FROM personal_prizes pp1
                    WHERE pp1.userId = 1 
                    GROUP BY pp1.group)
```

And it doesnt work.
So please help me to solve this problem.
And if you help to select prizes for user it will be great!

Comment: What is you expected output?

Comment: how do you join `prizes` with `personal_prizes`

Comment: @Kannan Kandasamy In this query - 2 and 6 for user with id = 1. In general - 'Second' and 'Ter' for this user. I use MySQL

Comment: Microsoft sql server or mysql?

Comment: @Ali It's a problem for me. I can't join these two tables for getting needed result((

Comment: what is this column `specId` ?

Comment: @Ali Oh, sorry. *specId* in personal_prizes is *id* in prizes

Comment: what do you mean by *" need to select highest title"* ?

Comment: @Ali I need to select specId by MAX(personal_prizes.id) GROUP BY personal_prizes.group. And then, based on this specIds, select prizes.title by prizes.Id

Answer (score 1):

The problem I perceive here is that prizes.id isn't really a reliable way to determine which is the "highest" prize. Ignoring this however I suggest using ROW_NUMBER() OVER() to locate the "highest" prize per user as follows:

Refer to this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e33da/6)

```
CREATE TABLE personal_prizes
    ([id] int, [userId] int, [specId] int, [group] int)
;

INSERT INTO personal_prizes
    ([id], [userId], [specId], [group])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 1),
    (2, 1, 2, 1),
    (3, 2, 3, 1),
    (4, 2, 4, 2),
    (5, 1, 5, 2),
    (6, 1, 6, 2),
    (7, 2, 7, 3)
;


CREATE TABLE prizes
    ([id] int, [title] varchar(7), [group] int)
;

INSERT INTO prizes
    ([id], [title], [group])
VALUES
    (1, 'First', 1),
    (2, 'Second', 1),
    (3, 'Newby', 1),
    (4, 'General', 2),
    (5, 'Leter', 2),
    (6, 'Ter', 2),
    (7, 'Mentor', 3)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
*
from (
    select
      pp.*, p.title
    , row_number() over(partition by pp.userId order by p.id ASC) as prize_order
    from personal_prizes pp
    inner join prizes p on pp.specid = p.id
    ) d
where prize_order = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e33da/6/0)**:

```
| id | userId | specId | group | title | prize_order |
|----|--------|--------|-------|-------|-------------|
|  1 |      1 |      1 |     1 | First |           1 |
|  3 |      2 |      3 |     1 | Newby |           1 |
```

The result can be "reversed" by changing the ORDER BY within the over clause:

```
select
*
from (
    select
      pp.*, p.title
    , row_number() over(partition by pp.userId order by p.id DESC) as prize_order
    from personal_prizes pp
    inner join prizes p on pp.specid = p.id
    ) d
where prize_order = 1

| id | userId | specId | group |  title | prize_order |
|----|--------|--------|-------|--------|-------------|
|  6 |      1 |      6 |     2 |    Ter |           1 |
|  7 |      2 |      7 |     3 | Mentor |           1 |
```

You could expand on this logic to locate "highest prize per group" too

```
select
*
from (
    select
      pp.*, p.title
    , row_number() over(partition by pp.userId, p.[group] order by p.id ASC) as prize_order
    from personal_prizes pp
    inner join prizes p on pp.specid = p.id
    ) d
where prize_order = 1


| id | userId | specId | group |   title | prize_order |
|----|--------|--------|-------|---------|-------------|
|  1 |      1 |      1 |     1 |   First |           1 |
|  5 |      1 |      5 |     2 |   Leter |           1 |
|  3 |      2 |      3 |     1 |   Newby |           1 |
|  4 |      2 |      4 |     2 | General |           1 |
|  7 |      2 |      7 |     3 |  Mentor |           1 |
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't do what I need((( I need to select _Second_ and _Ter_ for user wid userId = 1...

Comment: What is the **logic**? As I  stated the id in the prizes table isnt reliable. What, in the prizes table, indicates "highest"? You have it in your mind but you havent explained it to us.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I wrote it in comments but had to add in main post. It's my fault. The main idea is next. The _specID_ in _personal_prizes_ is _id_ in _prizes_. So at first, I need to select _specId_ by _MAX(id)_ GROP BY _group_ WHERE userId is specific user id.  After that, I need to select prizes by _id_. As I've written, personal_prizes.specId = prizes.id. So I have to select prizes based on previous results on specId. I want to implement by one query to DB

Comment: Sigh. I am well aware of how the 2 tables may be joined, as you can see i have used that relationship in my answer. What you have failed to explain is the measure of "highness". Are you saying that prizes.id 1 is "lowest" and that prizes.id 7 is "highest"? Or the opposite of that? Or is there some other way to arrive at this scale of prize "highness"? How to scale the most valued prize isn't clear. Once that is known just adjust the order by fileds within the over claise to suit that logic and you get the solution seek.